# About Joomla 4 Lazy Loading feature

Tags: development, joomla-4.x, template-override, performance

everyone.

I've read this: https://magazine.joomla.org/all-issues/january-2021/using-native-lazyloading-on-your-website, so it's clear to me that media images inserted in articles content will be lazy-loaded by default.

**What about the Intro and Full Article images on the "Images and links Tab"?**
Are they also lazy-loaded by default?
Is there any tweak I must use on overriding content templates?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Yes, both images are lazy loaded by default. These images are rendered using `layouts/joomla/content/intro_image.php` and `layouts/joomla/content/full_image.php` layouts which in turn use the `layouts/joomla/html/image.php` layout which is where the `loading` attribute is added and the `img` tag is rendered. If the `loading` attribute does not appear it could be that your template has a layout override that prevents these layouts from being used.